# AngularJS replace a list when clicked ng-click ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**HTML**

```
<ul class="feature-list-1">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in features" ng-click="featureSelect(key)">{{key}}</li>
</ul>
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
$scope.features =
{
    "administrative": [
        { id: 1, val: "Country"},
        { id: 2, val: "Province"},
        { id: 3, val: "Locality"},
        { id: 4, val: "Neighborhood"},
        { id: 5, val: "Land parcel"}
    ],
    "landscape": [
        { id: 1, val: "Man made"},
        { id: 2, val: "Natural"}
    ]
};

$scope.featureSelect = function(i) {
    $('.feature-list li').remove();
    $.each( $scope.features[i], function(i,v){
        $('.feature-list').append('<li>'+v.val+'</li>');
    });
}
```

I'm learning AngularJS and what I'm trying to do here is when the initial list an item is clicked it would either be `administrative` or `landscape`, I would like the list to clear and then the values replaced with the nested data with only Angular. in the example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kIQBjuGrpyP7wzUJxZYs?p=preview) I have used jQuery to replace the content and I know it isn't efficient because I would like to be able to do it correctly.

eg. if `landscape` is clicked the list would clear and be replaced by `Man made` and `Natural`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kIQBjuGrpyP7wzUJxZYs?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, have another list bound to a repeater:

```
<ul class="feature-list-1">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in features" ng-click="featureSelect(key)">{{key}}</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="feature in chosenFeatures">{{feature}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now for the Angular:

```
$scope.featureSelect = function(key) {
    $scope.chosenFeatures = $scope.feature[key];
}
```

Now when you choose, the `chosenFeatures` scope variable will get bound to the appropriate list and repeat out. Simple and clean.

Comment: Thank you! with some tinkering I was able to get it working. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Donald -- No problem! Be sure to mark the answer if it worked for ya!